# How to mock ExecuteUpdateAsync

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, nunit, ef-core-7.0

How to mock EF 7.0 ExecuteUpdate method.

Like SaveChangesAsync() how to mock set up the ExecuteUpdateAsync. I am using NUnit for unit test case

```
ExecuteUpdateAsync(a => a.SetProperty(u => u.IsActive, false))
```

This is how i setup the savechangesasync

```
 dbContext.Setup(s => s.SaveChangesAsync(It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(1);
```

Now my test case gets failed with the below message as i am not setting up the executeupdateAsync

> System.InvalidOperationException: There is no method 'ExecuteUpdate' on type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalQueryableExtensions'

Comment: IMO it's useless to mock this method. A green test says nothing whatsoever about what it'll do in the actual application.

Comment: As @GertArnold said, it's useless to mock EF code. You want to ensure you are using it correctly. Hence you need to run real code against real DB. It means you need to write integration tests rather than unit tests. Check the [testcontainers](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-dotnet) project. It can start a docker container with the required database for your tests.